# Multiple rotated text boxes with absolute page positions

Tags: positioning, pdftex, rotating, eso-pic

As part of a layout for a home made recipe book, I'm trying to lay out a series of text boxes at absolute positions on a page.  I'm using `eso-pic` to put a background image on the page which has openings for the text I'm trying to lay out such as ingredients and directions.

I'm currently using the `eso-pic` `AddToShipoutPictureFg` to handle each block of text which resides in a rotated minipage.  If I understand correctly, the arguments to `AddToShipoutPicture` will only get expanded at the end of the page.  This is creating problems when I'm using a changing definition such as a counter inside the `AddToShipoutPicture` macro.

Here is an example showing the method I'm using for multiple rotated text boxes.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright,letterpaper,11pt]{memoir}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\setcounter{mycounter}{1}

\begin{document}

% First chunk of angled boxed text.
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
    \put(2,6){% Or in my document \put(Xcoord,Ycoord)
        \begin{rotate}{45}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1in}
            This is some text.  I expect
            the counter to be 1, counter is \themycounter.
        \end{minipage}
        \end{rotate}
    }
}

\stepcounter{mycounter}
% Or in my document:
% \renewcommand{\Xcoord}{calculated X position}
% \renewcommand{\Ycoord}{calculated Y position}

% Second chunk of angled boxed text.
\AddToShipoutPictureFG*{
    \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
    \put(2,8){% Or in my document \put(Xcoord,Ycoord)
        \begin{rotate}{-30}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{1in}
            This is some more text.  I expect
            the counter to be 2, counter is \themycounter.
        \end{minipage}
        \end{rotate}
    }
}

\null

\end{document}
```

This is the result, showing that the counter's value is always at the last value set:

[image]

How can the expansion of the counter's value be forced at the time `AddToShipoutPictureFG` appears in the source text so that the output at the red arrow shows `1` rather than `2`?

NOTE 1: I'm a newbie using pdflatex.  If there's an easier way to get multiple rotated, absolute positioned text boxes on the page please advise.  I tried using the `rotating` package with `textpos` environment but they don't appear to play nice together - rotation occurs about a point in the text block that I can't determine.

NOTE 2: I've used a counter for the purposes of this example to illustrate a changing definition between `AddToShipoutPictureFG` calls.  What I have in my document in place of `\stepcounter{mycounter}` is a macro which redefines an X, Y coordinate pair for the following text box which is used inside the next `AddToShipoutPictureFG` call.  Of course the X, Y definitions at page end are the last X,Y set and so the text boxes always appear on top of each other rather than at the X,Y coordinate set before each `AddToShipoutPictureFG` call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put

```
\stepcounter{mycounter}
```

immediately after the  `\themycounter` so it is incremented after it is used. As is you are incrementing it on the main flow but using it twice in the output routine